# Is there a way to automatically extend a content block while typing?

Tags: html, css, positioning, containers, block

I want to know if there is a way to automatically extend content block by typing  or do I have to manually do it block by block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't define the width or height of the block in pixels and set width or height to auto then it will automatically extend content block.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be helpful to you

```
<div id="wrapper">content</div>

#wrapper
{
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#wrapper:after
{
content:".";
display:block;
clear:both;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/judearasu/VcQ44/